# Flask doesn't recognize POST method on heroku

Tags: python, flask, post, heroku, get

Im trying to make a post request but i get the error 405: method not allowed.

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
     return 'Hello World!'



@app.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def register_user():
    user_info = request.get_json()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = User.query.filter_by(username = user_info['username']).first()
        if user is not None:
            return jsonify({"msg":"User already exists!"}), 404
        saved_user = User(username=user_info['username'], password=user_info['password'])
        db.session.add(saved_user)
        db.session.commit()
        return ""
    return "", 200
```

and this is my request:

```
    r = requests.post('https://myapp.herokuapp.com/register',json = {'username':'testname','password':'testpsw'})
    assert r.status_code == 200
```

if i change it to
`methods = ['GET', 'POST']`
it just does a get.

Comment: try keeping the `user_info = request.get_json()` below the `request.method` line. Does the error still exists?

Comment: I tried it nothing happened :(

Comment: Could you maybe provide the error messages? Also do try placing print statements to figure out where exactly the code doesnt work. I tried this code locally replacing the code segment under `if request.method == 'POST':` with a print statement and it worked fine for me.

Comment: This is the error message when we run it in heroku ("GET /register HTTP/1.1" 405 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0").  So it makes a get method but I want a post.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line,

```
r = requests.post('https://myapp.herokuapp.com/register',json{'username':'testname','password':'testpsw'})
```

To this,

```
r = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/register', json = {'username':'testname','password':'testpsw'})
```

You need to assign the object to the second parameter "json" of the requests.post function for the request to work.

Comment: We want it on heroku not locally. Also added the = sign, thanks!